# Select permission was denied on object

Tags: sql-server, select, permissions

Well, I'm creating an app web with Cold Fusion, every time I debug my project in the browser I get this error:

> *Error Executing Database Query.*
>
> *[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer] The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'users', database 'hotel', schema 'dbo'*

I'm using a user called `CFLogin` and I grant to him select permissions through this command in SQL Server:

```
USE hotel
GO
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.users TO CFLogin
```

Also I've executed the follows stored procedures to give roles to my user:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner',CFLogin
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader',CFLogin
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_accessadmin',CFLogin
```

But it always results in the same message: `Select permission was denied on object...` I've even rebooted the service but nothing seems working at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Regards!

Comment: It would appear that you're connected under a different login - not CFLogin

Comment: try
Select user_ID(),User_name(),CURRENT_USER

Comment: I'm connected with CFLogin and that's select works, but not my select pointing to users table

Answer (score 6):

I also encountered a similiar issue while taking coldfusion enabled website in a Windows 2008 server running IIS 7. Executing the below queries helped resolve the issue for me,

```
use DATABASENAME
grant select on dbo.TABLENAME to public;
```

Executing the above query from sql prompt helped resolving this issue for me. Replace **DATABASENAME** and **TABLENAME** with your sql server database and tablename which is shown in error.

Comment: could you just grant permission to the user, rather than to all users? or am I misunderstanding this command?

Comment: Our DBA disallows to do that. Any other clues?